# Imprimir dados de um struct com valores lidos de um ficheiro de texto em C

Tags: c, arquivo, struct, io

Estou a tentar fazer um programa simples para ler dados de um ficheiro de texto, guardá-los num struct e imprimir esses dados no ecrã. O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 70

typedef struct
{
  int BI;
  float altura;
  int peso;
}PESSOA;

int main()
{
  PESSOA data[max];
  FILE *f;
  int N=0;
  f=fopen("dados2.txt", "r");
  if(f==NULL)
  {
    printf("Não foi possível abrir o arquivo.\n");
    return 0;
  }
  while(feof(f)!=0)
  {
    fscanf(f, "%d", &data[N].BI);
    fscanf(f, "%f", &data[N].altura);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &data[N].peso);
    printf("%d \n", data[N].BI);
    printf("%.2f \n", data[N].altura);
    printf("%d \n", data[N].peso);
    printf("\n");
    N++;
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

O ficheiro de texto possui o seguinte formato (repetido 65 vezes):

```
BI
Altura
Peso
```

Exemplo:

```
9914241  
1.55
99
1171804
1.80
63
1796075
1.64
85
```

O problema é que quando executo o programa não aparece nada no ecrã.
Alguém me consegue dizer o que estou a fazer mal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe um problema em usar `feof` desta maneira. Por exemplo, se o arquivo tiver uma linha em branco no final:

```
1 2.2 3
```

O `while` fará duas vezes a leitura dos números e a saída será algo do tipo:

```
1
2.20
3

32577
-1363474432.00
32577
```

Os 3 últimos números podem variar a cada execução ([veja no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/ImpartialUnwillingVariables#main.c) por exemplo, a cada execução os números mudam).

Se quiser uma explicação **bem** mais detalhada, pode ver [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941) e [aqui](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1046476070&id=1043284351). Mas basicamente, [`feof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/) verifica o [*end-of-file indicator*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/#indicators), não o arquivo em si. E quem seta o *end-of-file indicator* é outra função (no caso, uma das responsáveis por fazer a leitura).

Como o arquivo não termina depois da primeira linha, o *end-of-file indicator* ainda não está setado, então `feof` ainda indica que não chegou ao final do arquivo (e de fato não chegou mesmo). Somente depois do `fscanf` tentar ler a próxima linha é que será indicado que o arquivo chegou ao fim, mas aí já será tarde.

Situação similar ocorre se o arquivo estiver vazio: `feof` não sabe que o arquivo está vazio porque o *end-of-file indicator* ainda não foi setado (só depois que você tentar ler com `fscanf`, será verificado que ele está vazio), então ele entra no *loop* uma vez e será impresso o "lixo".

---

Uma maneira mais confiável é verificar o [retorno de `fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/#return), que é a quantidade de argumentos que foram corretamente lidos. Então basta ler todos os números de uma vez e verificar se o retorno é 3. Assim você garante que só vai imprimir quando de fato todos os valores foram corretamente lidos (caso contrário, o *loop* é encerrado):

```
while (fscanf(f, "%d%f%d", &data[N].BI, &data[N].altura, &data[N].peso) == 3) {
    printf("%d\n%.2f\n%d\n\n", data[N].BI, data[N].altura, data[N].peso);
    N++;
}
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/TestyDimgrayBase#main.c) a diferença. Repare que neste caso o *loop* será encerrado quando ele não conseguir ler os 3 números, ou seja, mesmo se não tiver chegado no final do arquivo, mas uma das linhas não tiver números (e tiver um texto, por exemplo), o `while` será interrompido.

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na utilização da função `feof`, mais especificamente na comparação do seu retorno.

A função `feof` retorna **0** quando o arquivo **não está em eof**, e *diferente de 0 quando o arquivo está em eof*.

---

Com isso, para corrigir o seu código, basta mudar a condição do seu `while`, podendo ficar da seguinte forma:

```
while(!feof(f))
```

Também poderia inverter a sua comparação, verificando se o retorno é igual a 0:

```
while(feof(f) == 0)
```

---

Seu código então ficará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 70

typedef struct
{
  int BI;
  float altura;
  int peso;
} PESSOA;

int main()
{
  PESSOA data[max];
  FILE *f;
  int N=0;

  f=fopen("dados2.txt", "r");

  if(f==NULL)
  {
    printf("Não foi possível abrir o arquivo.\n");
    return 0;
  }

  while(!feof(f))
  {
    fscanf(f, "%d", &data[N].BI);
    fscanf(f, "%f", &data[N].altura);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &data[N].peso);
    printf("%d \n", data[N].BI);
    printf("%.2f \n", data[N].altura);
    printf("%d \n", data[N].peso);
    printf("\n");
    N++;
  }

  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/AdoredPleasantColdfusion

---

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_feof.htm