# Leitura de números em C

Tags: c

Eu escrevi este código para ler vários números pelo teclado. Quero que a leitura termine quando o usuário pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Mas, quando eu pressiono <kbd>Enter</kbd>, ele continua esperando novas entradas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        int x;
        if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", x);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

É a primeira vez que programo em C. Alguém sabe como fazer com que o programa encerre a leitura quando o usuário pressionar uma nova linha?

Answer (score 2):

Se estiver rodando em um terminal, o que gera `EOF` é <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Linux/Unix) ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (Windows). Digitar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> gera uma entrada válida, então `feof` vai retornar falso e o *loop* continua.

Tem um outro detalhe aí: se você não digitar um número válido (por exemplo, "xyz"), o seu código entrará em *loop*, pois `scanf` não limpa esses caracteres do *buffer* de entrada.

Em vez disso, você poderia trocar `scanf` por `fgets`, que lê uma linha (tudo que foi digitado até o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), e depois de lido você verifica se só tem um <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, que no caso será representado pela quebra de linha (`\n` - já que o `fgets` inclui a quebra de linha na string lida):

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[20]; // defina um tamanho razoável para os números que você quer ler
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) { // se der erro na leitura (por exemplo, um EOF), sai do while
        if (buffer[0] == '\n') // se digitou somente ENTER, sai do while
            break;
        // tenta transformar em número (usando a base 10)
        printf("%ld\n", strtol(buffer, NULL, 10));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Depois de lido e verificado que não tem só uma quebra de linha, eu tento converter para número com `strtol`. O código ainda não é muito robusto porque não verifica se houve erro na conversão (que é um pouco chato de se fazer, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26083517) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176593)).
Também não trata os casos de ter mais de um número na mesma linha (separados por espaço, por exemplo), ou se digitar mais caracteres que o tamanho do buffer, etc. Enfim, C é uma linguagem "bruta" e permite/"exige" que na prática você mesmo acabe criando suas funções de entrada de dados, com os comportamentos específicos que você quer que tenha. Mas a ideia geral é essa.

---

Na verdade o assunto é mais amplo do que parece, pois cada detalhe do código pode desdobrar em um "mundo à parte" (como por exemplo "não usar `while (! feof)`", "evite `scanf` para ler entradas digitadas pelo usuário", etc). Portanto, recomendo que leia [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63822559), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45261521), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9427/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451503/112052), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434411) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537).