# Loop com feof(*stream) para ler arquivo lendo duas vezes a última linha

Tags: c, arquivo, io

O problema é:

> "Escreva um programa em C para ler um arquivo minusc.txt e escrever um arquivo maiusc.txt contendo o mesmo texto em maiúsculas."

E minha solução é:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANHO_DA_LINHA 500
#define ESPACO 32
#define INICIO_MINUSCULAS 97
#define FIM_MINUSCULAS 122

void linha_maiuscula (char *linha_da_vez, int tamanho_da_linha)
{
    for (int i=0; i<tamanho_da_linha; i++)
    {
        if (linha_da_vez[i]>=INICIO_MINUSCULAS && linha_da_vez[i]<=FIM_MINUSCULAS)
            linha_da_vez[i]-=32;
    }
}   

int main (void)
{
    FILE *arquivo_fonte, *arquivo_destino;
    char linha_da_vez[TAMANHO_DA_LINHA+1];

    arquivo_fonte = fopen("minusc.txt", "r");
    arquivo_destino = fopen("maiusc.txt", "w");

    while (!feof(arquivo_fonte))
    {
        fgets(linha_da_vez, TAMANHO_DA_LINHA, arquivo_fonte);
        linha_da_vez[strcspn(linha_da_vez, "\n")] = '\0';

        linha_maiuscula(linha_da_vez, TAMANHO_DA_LINHA);
    
        fprintf(arquivo_destino, "%s\n", linha_da_vez);
    }

    fclose(arquivo_fonte);
    fclose(arquivo_destino);

    return 0;
}
```

O problema que estou tendo é que ele está repetindo a última linha do arquivo `minusc.txt`, ou seja, se houver 5 linhas no arquivo minusc`.txt`, haverão 6 linhas no arquivo `maiusc.txt`, sendo que esta linha 6 é a repetição da 5, ou seja, ele entra mais de uma vez no laço `while`.

Conheço o comportamento da função `feof`, ela retorna 0 enquanto o indicador de fim de arquivo "EOF" não tiver sido atingido, mas ainda assim não entendo esse comportamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função [`feof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/) verifica o [*end-of-file indicator*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/#indicators), não o arquivo em si. O problema é que quem seta o *end-of-file indicator* é outra função (no caso, uma das responsáveis por fazer a leitura), por isso [não é uma boa ideia usar `feof` desta maneira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451503/112052). Ou seja, se tivermos algo como:

```c
while (! feof(arq)) {
    fgets(dados, tamanho, arq);
    // faz algo com os dados lidos
}
```

Isso pode dar problema, por exemplo, se o arquivo terminar com uma linha em branco. Quando chegar na última linha que tem dados, o `fgets` vai ler o seu conteúdo. Mas como ainda tem uma linha em branco no final, então `feof` vai retornar zero (já que `fgets` ainda não chegou ao final do arquivo, e portanto não setou o *end-of-file indicator*).

Na próxima iteração do `while`, `fgets` encontrará a linha em branco e o final do arquivo, e setará o *end-of-file indicator*. Mas nesse caso ele não conseguiu ler nada, e segundo a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), caso nenhum caractere seja lido, o conteúdo da string passada como primeiro argumento não é alterado (e isso resulta na última linha lida sendo escrita duas vezes, já que a string ainda contém os dados da leitura anterior que foi bem sucedida).

Se quiser uma explicação **bem** mais detalhada sobre o problema, pode ler [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941) e [aqui](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1046476070&id=1043284351).

---

Enfim, a solução é simplesmente não usar `feof`, e em vez disso testar o retorno do próprio `fgets` (assim você sabe se ele conseguiu ler os dados corretamente):

```c
int main (void) {
    char linha_da_vez[TAMANHO_DA_LINHA + 1];

    FILE *arquivo_fonte, *arquivo_destino;
    // sempre verifique o retorno das funções
    if ((arquivo_fonte = fopen("minusc.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo fonte\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((arquivo_destino = fopen("maiusc.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo destino\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // não use feof, em vez disso teste o retorno de fgets
    while (fgets(linha_da_vez, TAMANHO_DA_LINHA, arquivo_fonte)) {
        linha_maiuscula(linha_da_vez, TAMANHO_DA_LINHA);
        fprintf(arquivo_destino, "%s", linha_da_vez);
    }

    fclose(arquivo_fonte);
    fclose(arquivo_destino);

    return 0;
}
```

Outro detalhe é que eu não removi o `\n` depois de ler os dados, porque depois você acaba escrevendo novamente o `\n` no `fprintf`. Então removê-lo para depois adicioná-lo novamente me parece redundante e desnecessário. Simplesmente não o remova e na hora de escrever, não o adicione.

> Aliás, da forma que você fez **pode dar problema caso tenha alguma linha maior que o tamanho máximo** (pois neste caso o `fgets` não lerá o `\n`, mas na hora de escrever você inclui, fazendo com que o arquivo final fique com quebras de linha a mais). Faça o teste, mude `TAMANHO_DA_LINHA` para um valor pequeno, como `2` por exemplo (ou crie um arquivo com uma linha maior que `TAMANHO_DA_LINHA`), e veja o que acontece (e depois rode com o meu código acima para ver a diferença).

---

Como neste caso estamos escrevendo toda a string diretamente (inclusive o `\n`, caso tenha, já que eu não o removi), podemos usar [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs). `fprintf` é útil quando queremos formatar a saída, mas neste caso estamos escrevendo a string sem nenhuma formatação adicional, então basta escrevê-la diretamente com `fputs`:

```c
while (fgets(linha_da_vez, TAMANHO_DA_LINHA, arquivo_fonte)) {
    linha_maiuscula(linha_da_vez, TAMANHO_DA_LINHA);
    fputs(linha_da_vez, arquivo_destino);
}
```

---

Outro ponto é que a linha não necessariamente terá a quantidade de caracteres igual a `TAMANHO_DA_LINHA`, então não tem porque fazer o *loop* sempre até esse valor. Como `fgets` coloca o terminador de string no final, basta fazer o *loop* até encontrá-lo:

```c
void linha_maiuscula (char *linha_da_vez) {
    for (int i = 0; linha_da_vez[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (linha_da_vez[i] >= INICIO_MINUSCULAS && linha_da_vez[i] <= FIM_MINUSCULAS)
            linha_da_vez[i] -= 32;
}
```

<sup>*Eu também mudaria o nome da função para `converte_para_maiuscula` ou algo do tipo...*</sup>

Comment: Agradeço muito pela resposta, esse entendimento ainda vai me ajudar muito, corrigi todo meu código e já adotei as boas práticas. A única coisa que ficou estranho pra mim, foi o fgets dentro do while, de acordo com a documentação oficial, o retorno de fgets é a String ou NULL, como o while encara o retorno da string como algo verdadeiro, de modo que possa continuar a leitura? tem algum texto sugerido, já fiz isso algumas vezes e até hoje não entendo muito bem.

Comment: @RicardoFarias Basicamente, `while (fgets(...))` é equivalente a `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`. O valor `NULL` é avaliado como falso e qualquer ponteiro válido é verdadeiro (e uma string em C nada mais é do que um ponteiro para `char`). Portanto, enquanto o `fgets` não retornar `NULL`, o `while` continua. Veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/459743) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835035)