# Printar apenas parte do texto de arquivo com fgets

Tags: c

Olá, estou trabalhando com manipulação de .txt em um cadastro no c e estou com uma dúvida

Na função gets eu consigo printar tudo o que tem no texto, até o fim do arquivo, porém eu queria printar apenas a parte que interessa

Existem vários números de cadastro, cadastro 1,2,3 etc

Como faria pra eu poder printar apenas o cadastro número 2(por exemplo)

Pq quando chamo a função fgets, ele imprime tudo o que está cadastrado do cadastro 1 ao infinito

Essa é a parte do código que estou usando pra printar na tela os dados do texto:

```
{

arq = fopen("notas.txt", "r");
 if(arq == NULL)
   printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
 else{
    
    printf("Lendo o arquivo!");
    while(!feof(arq))
    {
        fgets(texto, 270, arq);
        printf("%s", texto);
    }
    printf("fim do arquivo");
        scanf("\n%d", &zero);
        fclose(arq);
        system ("cls");
        menu1();
}
```

Comment: Sem saber o formato do arquivo, não tem como sugerir muita coisa (apenas coisas mais "genéricas" e chutadas, como a resposta abaixo). É um cadastro por linha? O que tem em cada linha (número, seguido do nome, etc, por exemplo)? etc etc etc... Poderia [edit] e colocar algumas linhas do arquivo como exemplo? - Quanto a usar `feof`, sugiro que leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451503/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/540916/112052)

Answer (score 0):

Se os registros tiverem todos o mesmo tamanho, você pode calcular exatamente a posição em que estará o começo do registro. Digamos que cada linha tenha 15 caracteres; o segundo registro começa a partir do trigésimo caractere. O C tem a função `fseek()` ([ver documentação](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm)) que pula para qualquer região do seu arquivo. Neste exemplo, seria simplesmente dar o comando

```
fseek(arq, 30, SEEK_SET);
```

sendo `arq` o nome que deste ao arquivo, 30 o número de bytes que deseja pular e `SEEK_SET` uma referência ao começo do arquivo. Veja a documentação para mais detalhes.

Claro, como eu disse, isso só funciona se cada registro (linha, no seu caso) tiver exatamente a mesma quantidade de caracteres. Isso é uma situação rara de acontecer "naturalmente", mas geralmente vale a pena forçar uma padronização do tamanho do registro para ganhar essa vantagem.

Por exemplo, se estiveres fazendo uma lista de pessoas com suas respectivas idades, cada linha vai ter uma quantidade muito diferente de caracteres. A não ser que você defina que cada linha terá 97 espaços reservados para o nome das pessoas e mais 3 para suas respectivas idades. O resultado final é um arquivo muito mais pesado do que o necessário, pois muito frequentemente guardar o nome e idade de uma pessoa pode ser feito com uns 25 caracteres.

No entanto, você ganhou a enorme vantagem de consultar diretamente cada registro, sem precisar percorrer o arquivo inteiro para fazer isso. Isso permite realizar buscas e inserções muito mais rapidamente também.

Agora, caso esteja fora de questão padronizar o comprimento das entradas, dá para ir procurando linha a linha também. Não tem muito mistério, apenas vá consumindo as linhas até encontrar o que você procura. Se, por exemplo, você quiser imprimir o conteúdo da terceira linha do arquivo:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    fscanf(arq, "%d %d", &var1, &var2);
```

Isto vai consumir as três primeiras linhas, mas a última linha lida (que é a terceira) vai sobrescrever as anteriores. Não precisa ser `fscanf` necessariamente, pode inclusive ser um um loop de `fgetc`, porque o importante é contar quantas vezes o caractere `\n` apareceu na *filestream*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas no primeiro caso tem variáveis que se alteram de tamanho, já no segundo caso achei que poderia ser interessante pra esse caso, mas depois li que ele apaga as linhas anteriores, aí deixou de ser interessante, mesmo assim obrigado pelas sugestões, vou aguardar alguma outra resposta pra ver o que posso fazer

Comment: Ele não apaga as linhas anteriores. Ele lê, guarda os valores, mas os descarta quando a próxima linha é lida (já que você está escrevendo sempre sobre a mesma variável).

Comment: Ah sim entendi, então vou testar aqui, acho que vai ser esse o caso então, amanhã dou uma testada qualquer coisa já fecho o tópico! Vlw!!!